# How to enable popups in Google Calendar when tab is closed?

Tags: google-calendar

How do I enable popups in Google Calendar when tab is closed?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a Calendar lab called "Gentle reminders"

Go to your calendar settings and click the `Labs` tab at the top. Look for Gentle Reminders and click `Enable` then remember to save your changes.

Go back into your settings and you should now see (in the `General` tab) the options for Gentle Reminders. Try using desktop notifications - it will pop up a desktop notification near the system tray when an event is coming up.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

please see attached picture below from Google Help:

[image]